# plt.ion() recently changed behaviour

Tags: python, matplotlib, upgrade

The following python script does not display a figure anymore, as it used to on my machine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(1, 1)
plt.show() # Blocks and opens a graphical window as usual.

plt.ion()
plt.scatter(1, 1) # Does *not* open a graphical window anymore as I expect.
plt.scatter(2, 2) # Does *not* update the graphical window anymore as I expect (there is still no window at all)

plt.ioff()
plt.show() # The window opens at last, but it's blocking.
```

I also note that graphical windows style has changed (bottom bar):

[image: matplotlib new style]

My guess is that it is because my Arch system has recently upgraded to matplotlib `3.0.3-1`. But I see nothing about a major change in `ion()` on their [What's New](https://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html) page.

What could be causing this?
How do I get a non-blocking plot progressively updating like I used to get between two `ion()` and `ioff()` invokations?

---

**[UPDATE]** I can confirm that downgrading to matplotlib `2.2.3-2` does revert to expected behaviour. The problem thus seems to lie within recent upgrades of matplotlib or its environment.

**[UDPATE]** Filed on matplotlib [issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13661).

Comment: How are you running this that allows you to see in which exact line the window does or does not open up?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm running this line by line in a python3 interpreter (using [intim](https://github.com/iago-lito/intim), I if may take this opportunity to promote it a little). I can assert that the behaviour is the same when run with `$ python script.py` if I insert `sleep`, `print`, `input` functions *etc.* in between each pair of lines..

Comment: Running this interactively using python 3.6.8 and matplotlib 3.0.2 shows expected behaviour. Non-blocking plot is opened after first plot within `ion()` - `ioff()` and progressively updated. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 using conda environment.

Comment: I think you are correct. It does work as expected for me in an environment with matplotlib 2.2.3, and also in one with 3.0.2, but it fails when using the current development branch of matplotlib. (I do not currently have a 3.0.3 environment available). I suppose it would make sense to open an issue about this on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues). (Please use the normal python interpreter in a console, not some non-standard one you want to promote in that case.)

Comment: Actually it is more complicated. Even if I checkout the 3.0.2 version in the development branch it's not working correctly. This would suggest that it's not the matplotlib version that is responsible, but something else in the environment.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The python interpreter I am using is python `3.7.2`, and is standard (intim just passes lines to it). I'll post an issue to their tracker. Thank you for the pointer :)